# (Routing problem) Hosting .NET Core 5.0 MVC application on IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-5

I am having a problem when I deploy a WebApi and/or ASP.NET MVC application targeting the .NET 5 framework.

I created the Site and Application Pool and set the bindings as well. The Application Pool is set to No Managed Code and the Pipeline is set to Integrated.
I am using the same configurations as we use for all other .NET Core 3.x applications - we have 20-30 applications and WebApis.

I am getting a 404 error from the server when I try to open the URL. I figured out that there has to be a routing problem. When I call as specific action (https://myurl/home/index) I do get the correct response from the server.

I installed the ASP.NET Core Runtime 5.0.0 (Hosting Bundle) on the IIS webserver. Initialy I was getting this error with my .NET 5 WebApi I started to create with .NET 5 RC1.
So I created a new default MVC application and deployed it to the same server. Same issues here.

With the IIS Express localy it works just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: We are having a similar issue. A straigthforward Web API running smooth locally, but hosted on IIS it never responds. app pools are running fine, and nothing to be found in the  (windows) events/logs

Comment: Can you show me detailed 404 error page? you can try to add in the global.asax an Application_OnError and check in there the server.GetLastError.

Comment: When I open the application on the webserver it looks good. When I open the application from another machine within the local network I'll get the error. I noticed that when I enter the URL (https://myapplication.local/) the server redirects to https://myapplication.local/index.html which is wrong. The default routing should be https://myapplication.local/home/index

Comment: Do you use url rewrite in your IIS?  you can try to use failed request tracking to view the details of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the root of the problem.
A newly created .NET 5 web api project hides swagger by default if the environment is not development:

```
 if (env.IsDevelopment())
 {
     app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     app.UseSwagger();
     app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
         {
             c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Version 1.0");
             c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
         });
 }
```

This is of course the reason why the wep api itself works (e.g. with postman) but why we get a 404 error when trying to open Swagger in the browser.

So in my case I disable Swagger only in production:

```
 if (!env.IsProduction())
 {....}
```